# How to remove duplicates of the same code with different roles

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Change the text of the object's children and reassign them. 
I want to know the best way to clean up duplicate code.
The former stores the value, and the latter gets the value.

```
    public void OnClickKeypad()
    {
        RotateNumber();
    }

    public void RotateNumber()
    {
        transform.GetChild(0).GetComponent<UnityEngine.UI.Text>().text = ((int.Parse(transform.GetChild(0).GetComponent<UnityEngine.UI.Text>().text)+1) % 10).ToString();
        // "transform.GetChild(0).GetComponent<UnityEngine.UI.Text>().text" is a duplicate.
    }
```

Comment: Where is the duplicate?

Comment: If this is a general question about 'how to avoid duplicate code': use generics. If not, i don't get your question.

Comment: Is there any way to reduce the length of the code?

Comment: you made a 1 line method and called it, only way to make it shorter would be to not call the OnClickKeypad, and just assign rotateNumber to the onlclick...

Comment: Don't store numbers in text.

Answer (score 0):

If your problem is that you have to type `transform.GetChild(0).GetComponent<UnityEngine.UI.Text>().text` all over the place, then hide it behind a method or property getter with a useful name:

```
private UnityEngine.UI.Text firstTextChild => transform.GetChild(0).GetComponent<UnityEngine.UI.Text>();
```

Now you can use that from within that class:

```
firstTextChild.text = firstTextChild.text + "1";
```

Comment: Thank you. That's the answer I want. Is this a common way to use it?